# How do tectonic plates move upward?

Tags: plate-tectonics, tectonics, continent

And also, can this push continents and land-masses upward as well?I have not been informed of the phenomenon of tectonic plates rising up.
I am yet unable to find a satisfactory answer on the internet, be it in scholarly search engines or just Google.

Comment: What context are we talking about here? Can you give an example of a plate moving upward?

Comment: Hi @user8395.  I'm putting this question as "on hold" because it's not clear what your question is.  Please edit your question, then flag it for moderator attention so we can reopen it.